# Java Based Spring WebApp not Running Jetty9

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

I have a war project with Java Based Spring Configuration (without web.xml) that runs perfectly on mvn jetty:run but when I put inside the machines with Jetty 9 the project is not running. 
The jetty 9 server runs but the application doesn`t initialize at all.

The application consists in a Queue Subscriber.

It seems like I need to have a web.xml file.

Does anyone have an ideia what I`m missing?

The xml configuration file for the App on Jetty 9 server is (edit: with the correct conf file)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<!--
        JETTY_HOME="<%=node['api']['worker']['jetty']['jetty_home']%>"
        JAVA_HOME="<%=node['api']['worker']['jetty']['java_home']%>"
        JETTY_CONSOLE="<%=node['api']['worker']['jetty']['jetty_console']%>"
        JETTY_USER="<%=node['api']['worker']['jetty']['jetty_user']%>"
        JETTY_ARGS="<%=node['api']['worker']['jetty']['jetty_args']%>"
        JETTY_RUN="<%=node['api']['worker']['jetty']['jetty_run']%>"
        JAVA_OPTIONS="<%=node['api']['worker']['jetty']['java_options']%>"
-->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Get name="ThreadPool">
    <Set name="minThreads" type="int"><Property name="threads.min" default="10"/></Set>
    <Set name="maxThreads" type="int"><Property name="threads.max" default="200"/></Set>
    <Set name="idleTimeout" type="int"><Property name="threads.timeout" default="60000"/></Set>
    <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
  </Get>

  <Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler"/>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

  <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
    <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
    <Set name="outputBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.output.buffer.size" default="32768" /></Set>
    <Set name="requestHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.request.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
    <Set name="responseHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.response.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
    <Set name="sendServerVersion"><Property name="jetty.send.server.version" default="true" /></Set>
    <Set name="sendDateHeader"><Property name="jetty.send.date.header" default="false" /></Set>
    <Set name="headerCacheSize">512</Set>
  </New>

  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
    <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Arg name="factories">
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
            <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
          </New>
        </Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
    <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
    <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
    <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
    <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="http.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="http.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
  </New>

  <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty">
    <Arg>logback.configurationFile</Arg>
    <Arg>file:///conf/worker/logback.xml</Arg>
  </Call>
  <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty" >
    <Arg>service.config.path</Arg>
    <Arg>/opt/webapps/worker</Arg>
  </Call>


  <Set name="handler">
    <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
      <Set name="handlers">
        <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
          <Item>
            <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler">
              <Set name="showContexts">false</Set>
            </New>
          </Item>
        </Array>
      </Set>
    </New>
  </Set>

  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="." />/opt/webapps/worker.war</Set>
    <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
  </New>

  <Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
      <New id="DeploymentManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager">
        <Set name="contexts">
          <Ref refid="Contexts" />
        </Set>
        <Call id="webappprovider" name="addAppProvider">
          <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider">
              <Set name="monitoredDirName"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/webapps</Set>
              <Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>
              <Set name="extractWars">true</Set>
              <Set name="configurationClasses">
                <Array type="java.lang.String">
                  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
                  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
                  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
                  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
                  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item>
                  <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
                </Array>
              </Set>
            </New>
          </Arg>
        </Call>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

  <Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
  <Set name="stopTimeout">5000</Set>
  <Set name="dumpAfterStart"><Property name="jetty.dump.start" default="false"/></Set>
  <Set name="dumpBeforeStop"><Property name="jetty.dump.stop" default="false"/></Set>
</Configure>
```

The jetty-console log is

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
WARNING: System properties and/or JVM args set.  Consider using --dry-run or --exec
2014-12-19 19:32:49.749:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.0.3.v20130506
2014-12-19 19:32:49.800:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/opt/jetty- distribution-9.0.3.v20130506/webapps/] at interval 1
2014-12-19 19:32:51.554:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@45afc369{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-worker.war-_-any-/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/worker/worker.war}
2014-12-19 19:32:51.560:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/opt/jetty-distribution-9.0.3.v20130506/webapps/] at interval 1
2014-12-19 19:32:51.587:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@34cd072c{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

Edit: The xml configuration file is now correct and I had to uncomment the above options at `${jetty.home}/start.ini`

```
# ===========================================================
# Enable additional webapp environment configurators 
# -----------------------------------------------------------
OPTIONS=plus
etc/jetty-plus.xml

# ===========================================================
# Enable servlet 3.1 annotations
# -----------------------------------------------------------
OPTIONS=annotations
etc/jetty-annotations.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some obvious things to fix first.

1. You are using Java 8, upgrade to Jetty 9.2.6 (Jetty 9.0.3 is too old and does not support Java 8 well)
2. Your DTD reference is bad, it is the one from Jetty 7, it has been known to cause problems in Jetty 9.
   Use `<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">` instead.
3. Your class reference is bad, and should be fixed. `"org.eclipse.jetty_runˆy.server.Server"` doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for your response, I fixed those itens you notice, but the application are not running yet.
I found this [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404176) that explain why my application is not running. I made some changes and now I'm getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration` 
I need to make Jetty scan the lib folder to find this class but I don't know how!

Comment: That ClassNotFoundException means you dont have the `--module=annotations` enabled in your `${jetty.base}/start.ini`

Comment: Yeah! \o/ - It works now, thanks man. But I had to uncomment the annotations option and the plus option at `${jetty.base}/start.ini` I'll update the files at the question with the changes at start.ini.
Thanks a lot @JoakimErdfelt